# How to store Vietnamese characters in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

I wanted to add my colleague's information in my database for testing purposes. Since he his from Vietnam, his name has a special Vietnamese character in it ('ơ'). When I updated the database, the character was transformed to a regular 'o'...

How can I store that kind of special character inside SQL Server Express 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nvarchar and nchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(SQL.90).aspx)

> SUMMARY: Character data types that are
>   either fixed-length, nchar, or
>   variable-length, nvarchar, Unicode
>   data and use the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you'll need to use the nchar or nvarchar data type, and a client that supports unicode (such as Java or any .NET language).

Then, I'd expect it to just work..;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the NVARCHAR Data Type?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way is to make SQL server store the information using Unicode.